# Force div to Overflow instead of resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling with the problem of getting two columns with the same height.

[image: Two column with diffenrent height]

When the text isn't long enough then the two columns still have the same height. But otherwise, `<div>` auto-resize themselfes, make them have a different height.

I have tried using overflow-auto but it does not work.

Here is a fiddle of my work.
https://jsfiddle.net/kcaxy5Lh/1/

Comment: try this and provide the your height and it will have scroll. .mx-3 {
  overflow-y:auto;
  height:300px; /* change as per your need */
}

Comment: Make content `position: absolute;`. It wont affect height then.

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking for, you want both element to have equal height and they seem to do so in the fiddle you provided ? Try removing all unrelated code from the snippet and focus more on the issue.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I have deleted the unrelated code from the snippet. The issue was on the comment tab.

Comment: You want the comment tab to be the same height as the video ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Yes, i want it to overflow instead of auto resizing. I have tried `position: absolute;` as @M1K1O said but I dont know where to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way bootstrap establishes height is weird, they have `flex-wrap:wrap` on the class `.row` which prevent overflow from happening.

We need to remove that and change the layout to `flex-direction:column` then propagate the height downward.

```css
.info-tab {
  color: #BBB;
}

.comment {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* Comment section */

.comment-wrapper .media-list .media {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #efefef;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.user_name {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.comments-list .media {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

.title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.komen {
  font-size: 14px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* NEW */

#myTabContent,
#profile {
  height: 100%;
}

#profile>div {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#infoTab>div {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid bg-dark">

    <div class="row px-3">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 mt-5 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 h-100" id="player">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2lAe1cqCOXo&t" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 mt-5" id="infoTab">
        <div class="h-100 ml-2" style="border: 1px solid #555;">
          <div class="mx-3 h-100">
            <!-- Navication episode/comments -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill py-3" id="myTab" role="tablist">
              <li class="nav-item text-right mx-2">
                <a class="info-tab btn comment" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="comment" aria-selected="false">Comments</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <br>
            <!-- Navication Content -->
            <div class="tab-content mx-1 container overflow-auto" id="myTabContent">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active text-white f-right overflow-auto container" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                <!-- COMMENTs | https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/M5obX -->
                <div class="row py-1 overflow-auto">

                  <div class="col media p-0">
                    <div class="form-inline roundBorder mr-3">
                      <i class="form-inline fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #AAA;"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="media-heading title text-primary">Fahmi Arif</h4>
                      <p class="komen">
                        kalo bisa ya ndak usah gan biar cepetasdiojahdakssak<br> abc
                        <br>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="w-100"></div>

                  <div class="col media p-0">
                    <div class="form-inline roundBorder mr-3">
                      <i class="form-inline fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #AAA;"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="media-heading title text-primary">Fahmi Arif</h4>
                      <p class="komen">
                        kalo bisa ya ndak usah gan biar cepetasdiojahdakssak<br> abc
                        <br>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="w-100"></div>

                  <div class="col media p-0">
                    <div class="form-inline roundBorder mr-3">
                      <i class="form-inline fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #AAA;"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="media-heading title text-primary">Fahmi Arif</h4>
                      <p class="komen">
                        kalo bisa ya ndak usah gan biar cepetasdiojahdakssak<br> abc
                        <br>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="w-100"></div>

                  <div class="col media p-0">
                    <div class="form-inline roundBorder mr-3">
                      <i class="form-inline fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #AAA;"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="media-heading title text-primary">Fahmi Arif</h4>
                      <p class="komen">
                        kalo bisa ya ndak usah gan biar cepetasdiojahdakssak<br> abc
                        <br>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="w-100"></div>

                  <div class="col media p-0">
                    <div class="form-inline roundBorder mr-3">
                      <i class="form-inline fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #AAA;"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h4 class="media-heading title text-primary">Fahmi Arif</h4>
                      <p class="komen">
                        kalo bisa ya ndak usah gan biar cepetasdiojahdakssak<br> abc
                        <br>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="w-100"></div>

                </div>
                <!-- END COMMENT -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```